# Text seems pixelated and stretched on Zoom

Tags: android, android-canvas

Hi I am using a custom view with pinch zoom. But on zoom text looks  stretched on tablet.
But on android phone its perfectly OK. I am using the following code to draw text.

What I need to do so that text looks normal on zoom ? Why this problem is only on tablet ?

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setColor(0xff000000);
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
paint.setTextSize(cellWidth * 0.75f);
paint.setTextScaleX(cellWidth / cellHeight);
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

FontMetrics fm = paint.getFontMetrics();
float x = cellWidth /2 ;
float y = cellHeight/2  - (fm.ascent + fm.descent ) /2;
canvas.drawText(sb.toString(), x , y, paint);
```